# Virtual keyboard and tablet mode for KDE

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, laptop, tablet

I've just installed the last Ubuntu version with KDE.

I would love to use my convertible computer also in tablet mode but it seems not working at the moment. Is there any additional package you suggest to make it work, like for instance virtual keyboards, or something else that automatically detect tabled mode and starts the virtual keyboard?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onboard can do this. Add it to your tray or start it automatically. Now whenever input is requested by any application, onboard will open automatically.

Comment: I'm trying onboard, but there is no automatic way to make it start.. I have added an icon in the bar, but it's not the same..

Comment: you can start it on startup (using your DE, for GNOME System > Preferences > Startup Applications.) Then configure onboard: Settings -> Auto-show -> Show automatically when editing text
and in the convertible devices tab: Auto-show only in tablet mode.

Comment: I'm on KDE.. it's already enabled but unfortunately it doesn't work :/

Comment: I'll give you best answer anyway.. 2 weeks have passed, no solution :)

Answer (score 4):

This stuff is implemented, with a few caveats:

- It only works when using Wayland. On X11 there seem to be some ways to work around that though.
- The virtual keyboard only works for Qt apps, although there is ongoing work to improve this
- The tablet mode detection requires support for the hardware in the kernel, which sadly is missing sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if u are still searching for a way but one simple solution is adding the following as the last line in your `.bashrc` (`~/.bashrc`):

```
onboard &
```

For convertibles one can use `xinput test-xi2 --root` to detect if the display rotates "for me device 3 will returns some key presses" and start onboard / kill it giving a simple way of making tablet mode if the in build one is not working!

But its helpful to have the icon somewhere so you can press it in some cases when the app doesn't support qt. ;)

Comment: thank you mate, I'll try it